# Having problems with sql triggers

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

At the moment I am learning sql and begin to encounter problems with certain triggers.  This is very basic but I do not know how to solve it.

The problem is this: I have two tables `Person` and `BankAccountInfo`. The table Person`includes personal information. as identification number, name, birth date, etc. . The`BankAccountInfo` table contains banking information for each person in the Person table.

```
Person (ID number (12) primary key
      , name varchar (60)
      , phone number 
      , ...)

BankAccountInfo (ID number (12) references Person
                 , bankaccount number (8) primary key
                 , ...)
```

What I want is when I remove a person, the row for this person also be removed from the table BankAccountInfo, `DELETE Person WHERE ID = 123456`.

The problem is that I do not know how the information goes into the trigger

```
CREATE 
TRIGGER DELETEINFO
BEFORE DELETE ON Person
BEGIN
DELETE BankAccountInfo where ID = ?????? <- What do i put here?
END;
```

Comment: why would you ever delete bank account info? isn't there a 7 year requirement for this info?

Comment: i'm learning sql, its a example

Answer (score 9):

Is this Oracle? You should simply create a foreign key with delete cascade option of the parent table and Oracle will take care of deleting the bank account info when the person is deleted:

```
CREATE TABLE BankAccountInfo (
ID number (12) references Person ON DELETE CASCADE,
bankaccount number (8) primary key, ...)
```

Otherwise, if you still want to know how to access row values in Oracle triggers, use :new and :old implicit cursors (for delete trigger, :old.ID should do the trick).

More about constraints here:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_constraints.htm#i1006974

Comment: the 'ON DELETE CASCADE' is the ticket. You don't need triggers.

Answer (score 3):

Pop has it right with the ON DELETE CASCADE syntax.  However, if you do want to use a trigger the syntax is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER DELETEINFO
BEFORE DELETE ON Person
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DELETE BankAccountInfo where ID = :OLD.ID;
END;
```